# Get all the users that has only 1 category in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table with U that represents "User" and C that represents "Category". I need a way to query how many categories a user has and limit that to 1. So basically, I need to get all the users that has only 1 category. How can this be achieved with SQL (PostgreSQL)?

I've tried to find any solution on Stackoverflow for a while now, but without success.

```
id  U   C
1   3   5
2   1   3
3   3   5
4   5   2
5   11  5
6   11  5
```

**Expected result:**

```
id  U   C
1   1   3
2   5   2
```

Comment: What's the expected result, and why?

Comment: Hi Marcus, please also add what you've tried so far.

Comment: Added expected result now to illustrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is easy with the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT max(id), u, max(c)
FROM atable
GROUP BY u HAVING count(c) = 1
```

Comment: It's not quite this simple because it'll complain about id not being in the group by clause; I've updated your answer.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. I fixed it.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks, but with my amount of rows, it crashes the whole GUI after 1 million rows.

Comment: But the numbet of rows won't be different no matter how you query, right? You can add a `LIMIT` to limit the number of result rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***window functions*** for your purpose.

[Window Functions](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/#:%7E:text=Similar%20to%20an%20aggregate%20function,the%20rows%20in%20a%20window.)

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM(
SELECT a.*,count(c)over(partition by id) as cnt
FROM testtable a
) WHERE CNT=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no duplicates, you can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.u = t.u and t2.c <> t.c);
```

If you have duplicates of `u`/`c`, just use `id`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.u = t.u and t2.id <> t.id);
```

If you want to reassign a sequential number, then use `row_number()` as well:

```
select row_number() over (order by id) as new_id, t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.u = t.u and t2.c <> t.c);
```

Comment: Thanks! How to change this to handle duplicates?

Comment: @Marcus . . . You can use `id` instead of you want to guarantee one *row* -- even when multiple rows might have the same `u` and `c` value.